# dropdown dependency change in php or codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have two dropdowns with same values.one is single select and another with multiple selection. If a select one value then the same value in another dropdown shouldn't be displayed or it should be hide. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: You'll need to use ajax to achieve this

Comment: <select name="joblocation" id="joblocation" data-menu-style="dropdown-blue"  class="selectdesign">
                                                <option value="">Please select joblocation</option>
            <option value="Banglore">Banglore</option>
            <option value="Chennai">Chennai</option>
            <option value="Hyderabad">Hyderabad</option>
            <option value="Mumbai">Mumbai</option>
            <option value="Pune">Pune</option>
                                                </select>

Comment: javascript, jquery etc. if you need it *right now* then split it up into 2 forms.